# tell me the sql

Tags: sql

I have a table like this.

**Table name : message**

```
mid | mfrom | mto | msg
------------------------   
1   |  a    |  b  | hi
2   |  b    |  a  | hello
3   |  a    |  c  | how are you
4   |  c    |  a  | fine
```

i am able to show all rows by

```
`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM message
WHERE mto = '$to'
OR mfrom = '$to';");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo $row['msg'];
}`
```

but i want to show only one result if `mfrom` and `mto` or `mto` and `mfrom` is equal. Such as if `mfrom =a` and `mto=b` or `mfrom=b` and `mto=a`. I want to show only one result from them like this

```
mid | mfrom | mto | msg 
-------------------------
2   |  b    |  a  | hello
4   |  c    |  a  | fine
```

please tell me the query.

Comment: You will have to explain a bit more what you want

Comment: `SELECT * FROM message WHERE mto = 'a';` Not sure what result you are actually trying to retrieve is

Comment: I guess you want messages sent to user a ie `where mto='a'`

Comment: i want to show only one result if  mfrom and mto or mto and mfrom is equal. Such as
if mfrom =a and mto=b or mfrom=b and mto=a. I want to show only one result from them

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: i don't understand RDBMS. Please give me a example. I am new in php ane sql

Comment: Like `Mysql`,`Orcale`,`Sql Server`,`DB2`, etc..

Comment: sql.
Like
SELECT * FROM message WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear because your "query" seems wrong ("mfrom and mto or mto and mfrom is equal" doesn't seem correct).

Nevertheless, as you named the table "message", I'm guessing that you want each message once even though it appears twice in the table.

What you could do is query from the table "twice" and then use the bigger of the ids:

```
SELECT first.* FROM message AS first LEFT JOIN message AS second 
    ON first.mfrom = second.mto AND first.mto = second.mfrom
    WHERE first.mid > second.mid OR second.mid is NULL;
```

This would give you the result you requested. It would also give you any message that doesn't have a "partner" row.

If you want only matching messages, you can remove the "OR second.mid is NULL".